# Yii ajax dropdown list not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii

hello im so confused with my problem
the problem is the ajax didnt update the value
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsR9S.png) 
while i choose kegiatan ajax didnt react/update.
idk were the error

please help me

this my controler code

```
public function actionDynamiclocation()
{
    $data=Kegiatan::model()->findAll('nid=:nid', 
                  array(':nid'=>(int) $_POST['nid']));

    $data=CHtml::listData($data,'nid','lokasi','pengajuan','realisasi');
    foreach($data as $value=>$name)
    {
        echo CHtml::tag('option',
                   array('value'=>$value),CHtml::encode($name),true);
    }
}

 public function actionAjaxCreate() {$model=new Reportbean;
     $outlets = Kegiatan::model()->findAll('nid=:nid', 
                  array(':nid'=>(int) $_POST['nid']));

     $model->lokasi=0;
     $model->pengajuan=1;
     $model->realisasi=2;

     $this->renderPartial('_keg ', array('model'=>$model),false,true);


}
```

and view code

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'kegiatan'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->DropDownList($model,'kegiatan',
        array(),
        array(
            'empty'=>'--pilih--',
            'ajax' => array(
                'type'=>'POST', //request type
                'url'=>CController::createUrl('Reportbean/ajaxCreate'), //url to call.
                'data'=>array('nid'=>'js:this.value'),
                'update'=>'.outlet',
                //'update'=>'#'.CHtml::activeId($model,'lokasi'), //selector to update
                //'data'=>array('nid'=>'js:this.value'),
            ))); ?>


    <div class="outlet">
    <?php
         $this->renderPartial('_keg', array('model'=>$model),false,true);
    ?>
    </div>

<?php
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
        'data'=>$model,
        'id'=>'keg',
        'attributes'=>array(
            'lokasi',
            'pengajuan',
            'realisasi',

        ),
        ));
    ?>
```

Comment: I think it might just be a matter of sending the request to the correct URL.

Comment: ohh isee i add foreach ($outlets as $key => $value) {
   $value->lokasi;
   $value->pengajuan;
   $value->realisasi;  for the problem solve